# Could not authenticate you from GoogleOauth2, Devise. Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth, omniauth-google-oauth2

I trying to authenticate with Google and Devise Gem
at the final stage, I receive a flash message: Could not authenticate you from Google because user@gmail.com is not authorized. Therefore, I cannot log in

logs:

```
DEBUG -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Request phase initiated.
Started GET "/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback?state=bfcb81a9dc331af478dcd5ccb3dda620894b0e577d1fabe8&code=4%2F0AX4XfWifE4F2PzgdO28g5GSMPg28WltztgoSpJHfM-CsQl8oplhFAKix-WJZAf9LRREIHw&scope=email+openid+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fcontacts.readonly+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fuserinfo.email&authuser=0&prompt=none" for ::1 at 2021-07-23 11:59:55 +0300
D, [2021-07-23T11:59:55.042930 #13482] DEBUG -- omniauth: (google_oauth2) Callback phase initiated.
Processing by Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#google_oauth2 as HTML
 Parameters: {"state"=>"bfcb81a9dc331af478dcd5ccb3dda620894b0e577d1fabe8", "code"=>"4/0AX4XfWifE4F2PzgdO28g5GSMPg28WltztgoSpJHfM-CsQl8oplhFAKix-WJZAf9LRREIHw", "scope"=>"email openid https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "authuser"=>"0", "prompt"=>"none"}
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPT5J.png)

Comment: Can you share exact prompt screenshot ? Are you giving user@gmail.com as an example or are you using exactly this email as test email ?

Comment: I am using a really existing mail

Comment: did you figure this out? I have the same issue, my email is in the test emails field on the google console for my app

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might need to create Google authorization credentials for your app. Take a look at https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in#create_authorization_credentials.